Cauchy Schwarz correlation inequality
I'm wondering where am I wrong.
Lets say joint expectation is given by $E[XY] = \sum\sum{x_iy_j p_{X, Y}(x_i,y_j)} = x^T P y$ where $P \in R^{n \times n}$ probabilities assigned to states of $X, Y$. Correspondingly $X$ and $Y$ both have $n$ states.
Lets say $P$ can be represented as product of marginal probabilities so $P = P\vec{1} \cdot \vec{1^T}P$.
Having said that we can represent joint expectation as dot product $E[XY] = \langle x^T P \vec{1}, \vec{1^T}P y\rangle$. May I be wrong concluding it?
Then by Cauchy-schwarz inequality $\langle x^T P \vec{1}, \vec{1^T}P y\rangle^2 \leq \langle x^T P \vec{1}, x^T P \vec{1}\rangle \cdot \langle \vec{1^T}P y, \vec{1^T}P y\rangle$, ie $E[XY]^2 \leq E^2[X] E^2[Y]$.
But I know that in proper proof $E[XY]^2 \leq E[X^2]E[Y^2]$. So I've made a mistake somewhere. Would appreciation any elaborations =)

$E[XY] \leq E[X^2]E[Y^2]$ is wrong. Eg: $X=\frac  1 2, Y=1$.

@geetha290krm thanks, yep I forgot, added square

Already, I got what is wrong.
$P_X = P\vec{1}$ and $P_Y = \vec{1^T}P$ marginal probabilities. When multiplied with corresponding $X, Y$ states yields some $R$. We can think of two real values as vectors $\in R$, so by definition they're linear dependent.
By Cauchy-Schwarz if $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$ are linear depend, inequality reduces to equality. Ultimately we have
$$
E[XY] = \langle x^T P\vec{1} \cdot\vec{1^T} P y\rangle \stackrel{(a)}{=} E[X]E[Y] \\
\langle x^TP\vec{1}, \vec{1^T}Py\rangle^2 \stackrel{(b)}{\leq} \langle x^TP\vec{1}, x^TP\vec{1}\rangle \cdot \langle \vec{1^T}Py, \vec{1^T}Py\rangle \rightarrow \\
\langle x^TP\vec{1}, \vec{1^T}Py\rangle^2 {\color{red}=} \langle x^TP\vec{1}, x^TP\vec{1}\rangle \cdot \langle \vec{1^T}Py, \vec{1^T}Py\rangle \rightarrow \\
E[XY]^2 = E^2[X]E^2[Y]
$$
where in (a) I just note that it is equal to product of expected values.
where inequality (b) by linear dependence turn to equality.
Also should note, that those marginal probabilities are viable only for independent rvs. Hence we see that $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$
